# How to make .replace script "digit-case-sensitive"?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple side-project here to help me at work. What I have is a script that will replace a specified number with another.

My problem now though is, I cannot find a way to make it "digit-case-sensitive" (I'm not sure what it's called sorry), meaning, if I want to change the following, they replace only the specified and not anything else. For example:

10 = 80 
1 = 75 
0 = 65

The problem is, if I replace **10**, there's a tendency that it will become 865.

It's changing 10 to 80 first and then the 0 to 65.

Now I really need help as to how do I make the replace script to the specified digit only and not cut the digits or take only half and change them.

Also, how can I make it so that it changes only once for 1 click of button? In this case, it's processing it twice with 1 click of button. It changes 10 to 80 first and then the 0 to 65. What I'd like is run the script only once per click. In this flawed script, it should only be 65 and not process the 0 to 65, since doing so should take 2 clicks.

Here's my sample code, there will be thousands of digits to replace once I move on from this obstacle.

```js
function fixTextarea(textarea) {
  textarea.value = textarea.value.replace("", "")

    
    .replaceAll("10", "80")
    .replaceAll("1", "75")
    .replaceAll("0", "65")

};

function fixtext() {
  let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea1");
  textarea.select();
  fixTextarea(textarea);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  var area = document.getElementById("textarea1");

  var getCount = function(str, search) {
    return str.split(search).length - 1;
  };

  var replace = function(search, replaceWith) {
    if (typeof(search) == "object") {
      area.value = area.value.replace(search, replaceWith);
      return;
    }
    if (area.value.indexOf(search) >= 0) {
      var start = area.selectionStart;
      var end = area.selectionEnd;
      var textBefore = area.value.substr(0, end);
      var lengthDiff = (replaceWith.length - search.length) * getCount(textBefore, search);
      area.value = area.value.replace(search, replaceWith);
      area.selectionStart = start + lengthDiff;
      area.selectionEnd = end + lengthDiff;
    }
  };

});
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1">10</textarea>

<button onclick="fixtext()">Update</button>
```

I apologize in advance for not being able to make myself too clear.

Answer (score 3):

You could replace with searching for alternative strings and take the longest first.

---

For prevent changing the value again on a click, store the orginal value to a  `data-*` attribute.

```js
const
    replace = s => s.replace(/10|1|0/g, s => ({ 10: '80', 1: '75', 0: '65' }[s]));

console.log(replace('1010'));
console.log(replace('01'));
```

Comment: Thank you I will try to experiment with this script you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the replace in an `if` `else if` `else` block

```js
function fixTextarea(textarea) {
  

    if(textarea.value === "10"){
     textarea.value = textarea.value.replace("", "").replaceAll("10", "80") 
    }else if(textarea.value === "1"){
       textarea.value = textarea.value.replace("", "").replaceAll("1", "75")
    }else{
     textarea.value = textarea.value.replace("", "").replaceAll("0", "65")
    }
   
    
  
};

function fixtext() {
  let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea1");
  textarea.select();
  fixTextarea(textarea);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  var area = document.getElementById("textarea1");

  var getCount = function(str, search) {
    return str.split(search).length - 1;
  };

  var replace = function(search, replaceWith) {
    if (typeof(search) == "object") {
      area.value = area.value.replace(search, replaceWith);
      return;
    }
    if (area.value.indexOf(search) >= 0) {
      var start = area.selectionStart;
      var end = area.selectionEnd;
      var textBefore = area.value.substr(0, end);
      var lengthDiff = (replaceWith.length - search.length) * getCount(textBefore, search);
      area.value = area.value.replace(search, replaceWith);
      area.selectionStart = start + lengthDiff;
      area.selectionEnd = end + lengthDiff;
    }
  };

});
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1">10</textarea>

<button onclick="fixtext()">Update</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'd experiment if I can use this for thousands of replaces. This looks really good.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to be a little creative, by changing "10" to something that has special meaning so that the match on "0" won't change it, then change it to your end result:

```
function fixTextarea(textarea) {
  textarea.value = textarea.value.replace("", "")

    
    .replaceAll("10", "xx")
    .replaceAll("1", "75")
    .replaceAll("0", "65")
    .replaceAll("xx", "80")

};
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, for this I initially tried adding a comma after a digit. It's working fine, until it gets mixed with thousands more digits. And it's really impossible for now to manually think of such possible combinations since there's really a lot.. So I'm really hoping to see a good script solution. But thank you sir really!